# SWR size, setSize do not exist on type SWRResponse<any, any>?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, swr

I've been testing [Vercel's SWR](https://swr.vercel.app) lately, it looks like the best lib for Next.js data fetching. I have some trouble making it work with TypeScript though.

As in [docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/pagination#useswrinfinite) I'm trying to build a infinite loader using this code:

```
const { data, error, isValidating, mutate, size, setSize } = useSWRInfinite(
  getKey, fetcher?, options?
)
```

But I'm getting those errors:

```
Property 'size' does not exist on type 'SWRResponse<any, any>'.ts(2339)
Property 'setSize' does not exist on type 'SWRResponse<any, any>'.ts(2339)
```

The rest of the arguments seem to be there, only the last two aren't. What am I missing here? It works perfectly fine without TypeScript. I have both latest versions of Next and SWR. I've tried following the tutorial and adding getKey function, but without luck, the error always occurs.

Any hints?

Comment: What version of `swr` do you use and how do you import the `useSWRInfinite` hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that TypeScript identifies the return type as `SWRResponse` indicates that you're probably importing the default export (`useSWR` hook) of `swr` rather than `useSWRInfinite` hook.

```js
import useSWR from 'swr'
```

Make sure to import `useSWRInfinite` from its named export.

```js
import { useSWRInfinite } from 'swr'
```

---

From **version 1.x**, the syntax to import `useSWRInfinite` changed slightly. You should now use:

```
import useSWRInfinite from 'swr/infinite'
```

Comment: `import useSWR from 'swr'` but `import { useSWRInfinite } from 'swr'`, you were right. Really annoying, copied `useSWR` from different file, added `Infinite`, and bam, trouble! Thank you.

Comment: What version of swr are you using? I am getting `Module '"swr"' has no exported member 'useSWRInfinite'. Did you mean to use 'import useSWRInfinite from "swr"' instead` error if I do import { useSWRInfinite}

Comment: @Toxnyc That answer was for versions pre-1.x - from version 1.x onwards you should import it as `import useSWRInfinite from 'swr/infinite'`. I've updated my answer.